# Features becomes bigger on zooming in Openlayers 2.13

Tags: features, openlayers-2, scale

i'm new in developing Openlayers applications.I want to add Points and LinearRing objects to the same layer. My Problem is, when I add a LinearRing and I am zomming in, the geometry gets bigger and bigger on every zoom level. But the LinearRing should have the same behaviour as a Point. When I am zooming, the point is automatically scaling so it becomes a little bit smaller and not bigger!

Here are some pictures to understand my problem:
First picutre show how it looks like without zoom:
[image]

Second picutre show how it looks like with zoom:
So as you can see, the LinerRing beomces very big.

[image]

I hope you can understand my problem and somebody can give me a good solution.